# "Failed to open Xillybus device file(s) while running host application on zedboard running Xillinux

Tags: c++, c, embedded-linux, fpga, xilinx

I am writing a code where I have to read from input files and then read the output. One of the files is large and is around `38 MB`. I'm not very good at programming so by looking at some tutorials and `xillybux` programming guide, I wrote the following code to read from two files, write them to the logic and then read them. My motive is to calculate the time of reading and writing for my future project. But when I try to run the program I get the following error

```
Failed to open Xillybus device file(s), device resource busy
```

I don't know what I have done wrong. The code which I had written is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#define N ((cols+1)*rows + cols) 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int fdr, fdw;
    FILE *ftime_rw;
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *U, *V, *RI;
    int rc, donebytes;
    int *tologic, *fromlogic;
    pid_t pid;
    int i,j;
    struct timeval tv1, tv2;
    double time_rw;
    char *buf;
    int temp;
    int rows= 575;
    int cols= 18689;

    fdr = open("/dev/xillybus_read_32", O_RDONLY);
    fdw = open("/dev/xillybus_write_32", O_WRONLY);

    if ((fdr < 0) || (fdw < 0)) 
    {
        perror("Failed to open Xillybus device file(s)");
        exit(1);
    }

    U = fopen("U.txt", "r"); 
    V = fopen("V.txt", "r");  
    RI = fopen("RI.txt", "a");

    if(U==NULL || V==NULL || RI==NULL )
    { 
        printf("Write in their respective files!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) // Read 
    { 
        fscanf(U,"%d", &temp);
        fprintf(RI,"%d\n", temp);
    }

    for(j=0; j<rows; j++)
    { 
        for (i=0; i<cols; i++) // Read 
        { 
            fscanf(V,"%d", &temp);
            fprintf(RI,"%d ", temp);
        }

        fclose(U);
        fclose(V);
        fclose(RI);


        tologic = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* N);

        if (!tologic) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        RI = fopen("RI.txt", "r");

        for(j=0; j<rows; j++)
        { 
            for (i=0; i<cols; i++)
            fscanf(RI,"%d", &tologic[N]);

            fclose(RI);

            pid = fork();  // writer + reader

            if (pid < 0) 
            { 
                perror("Failed to fork()");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (pid) // writer process
            {
                close(fdr);
                buf = (char *)tologic;
                donebytes=0;

                gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);  // start count time

                while (donebytes < sizeof(int)*N)  // write N integers
                {
                    rc = write(fdw, tologic + donebytes, sizeof(int)*N - donebytes);

                    if ((rc < 0) && (errno == EINTR))
                        continue;

                    if (rc <= 0) 
                    {
                        perror("write() failed");
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    donebytes += rc;
                }
                gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);  // stop count time

                time_rw = (double) (tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec);

                printf("Writer. Total time = %f usec\n", time_rw); 

                if(close(fdw)==-1)
                    printf("ERROR closing write_32 file!\n");

                return 0;
            } 
            else  // reader process
            {
                close(fdw);
                fromlogic =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* N);

                if (! fromlogic)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                buf = (char *)fromlogic;
                donebytes = 0;

                donebytes = 0;

                gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);  // start count time

                while (donebytes < sizeof(int)*rows)  // read num_rows integers 
                {
                    rc = read(fdr, fromlogic + donebytes, sizeof(int)*rows - donebytes);

                    if ((rc < 0) && (errno == EINTR))
                        continue;

                    if (rc < 0) 
                    {
                        perror("read() failed");
                        exit(1);
                    }

                    if (rc == 0) 
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Reached read EOF!? Should never happen.\n");
                        exit(0);
                    }

                    donebytes += rc;
                }

                gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);  // stop count time

                time_rw = (double) (tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec);

                printf("Reader. Total time = %f usec\n", time_rw);

                for (i=0; i<rows; i++)  // Integers read from logic
                    printf("Reader process : %d\n", fromlogic[i]);

                sleep(1); // Let debug output drain (if used)

                if(close(fdr)==-1)
                    printf("ERROR closing read_32 file!\n");

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```